# C# run expression on property

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression

I'm quite new to c# Expressions. I already figured out that they are very powerfull.
I am using them for authorizations.

```
public static Expression<Func<myType, bool>> MyTypeTableFilter(string userid, string tablename, bool hideOwnDossier)
{
    var e1 = MySecondTypeAuthorizationFilters.HasMySecondTypeTableFilter<myType>(userid, tablename, hideOwnDossier);
    var e2 = MyThirdTypeAuthorizationFilters.HasMyThirdTypeTableFilter<myType>(userid, tablename, hideOwnDossier);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<myType, bool>>(Expression.OrElse(new SwapVisitor(e1.Parameters[0], e2.Parameters[0]).Visit(e1.Body), e2.Body), e2.Parameters);
}
```

I've the following method. It allows me to filter like this:

```
query = query.Where(MyAuthorizationFilters.MyTypeTableFilter("str", "", bool));
```

Now I have another type that has a property of the type: 'myType'.

I want to recylce the first expression by calling it on my second function:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> HasMyTypeTableFilter<T>(string userid, string tablename, bool hideOwnDossier)
            where T : class, IHasMyType
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tablename))
        tablename = typeof(T).Name;

    x=>x.myType // something like 'where' MyTypeTableFilter
}
```

So the 'x' in this function has a single property called 'mytype' of type 'MyType'. It's a single property, so no list or whatever. I want to run the first expression on x.mytype.
Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance!

But I can't seem to find a way to achieve this. I also find it hard to Google since I don't know the right terms. Can anybody help me with this expression?

Comment: What purpose that you use Expression in this case? I mean could you explain those `AuthorizationFilters` working?

Comment: The authorization functions checks for userrights with the query. So it does something like this: x => x.property  in userrights